# Virtual Box: USB not working (host: Ubuntu 16.04) in Win10 (guest)

Tags: 16.04, usb, virtualbox, windows-10

I got the latest extension pack installed, I got "USB2" activated in VB menu, and added a "new filter" there (for all detected USB's not some special).

Unfortunately Ubuntu still doesnt "permit" my guest OS to use the USB ports, so I ended up with the following terminal command, that I found:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username
```

After that I was supposed to look up the USB-devices with:

```
vboxmanage list usbhost
```

but the list was empty.

Any idea what I can do? Most tutorials I found here were for older versions, so I dont know if they still up to date?

Comment: Did you install the guest additions in the Win10 guest vm ? If not, so this is what is missing.

Comment: cmak.fr guest additions have been already installed and upgraded to latest version, still USB doesnt work...